# Unexpected parallelstream performance in Java 8

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I experienced a performance issue when using the stream created using the  `spliterator()` over an Iterable. ie., like `StreamSupport.stream(integerList.spliterator(), true)`. Wanted to prove this over a normal collection. Please see below some benchmark results.

Question:
Why does the parallel stream created from an iterable much slower than the stream created from an ArrayList or an IntStream ?

**From a range**

```
 public void testParallelFromIntRange() {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    IntStream stream = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE).parallel();
    System.out.println("Is Parallel: "+stream.isParallel());
    stream.forEach(ParallelStreamSupportTest::calculate);
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("ParallelStream from range Takes : " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert((end - start),
            TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) + " milli seconds");
}
```

**Is Parallel: true

ParallelStream from range Takes : 490 milli seconds**

**From an Iterable**

```
 public void testParallelFromIterable() {
    Set<Integer> integerList = ContiguousSet.create(Range.closed(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE), DiscreteDomain.integers());
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    Stream<Integer> stream = StreamSupport.stream(integerList.spliterator(), true);
    System.out.println("Is Parallel: " + stream.isParallel());
    stream.forEach(ParallelStreamSupportTest::calculate);
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("ParallelStream from Iterable Takes : " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert((end - start),
            TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) + " milli seconds");
}
```

**Is Parallel: true 

ParallelStream from Iterable Takes : 12517 milli seconds**

And the so trivial calculate method.

```
public static Integer calculate(Integer input) {
    return input + 2;
}
```

Comment: Does `ContinguousSet` actually have proper `spliterator`? Guava is not optimised for Java 8 whereas the JDK obviously is.

Comment: Does `ContiguousSet.spliterator()` return a sized spliterator, or one of unknown size? That might affect how the data is split among threads. You can use [`Spliterators.spliterator(Iterator, long, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterators.html#spliterator-java.util.Iterator-long-int-) to create a spliterator from an iterator and the size of the set.

Comment: Where does an Iterable come into play in the second example? If there is one in there, note that an Iterable is inherently sequential, since the only access to elements is via `hasNext`/`next`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not all spliterators are created equally.  One of the tasks of a spliterator is to decompose the source into two parts, that can be processed in parallel.  A good spliterator will divide the source roughly in half (and will be able to continue to do so recursively.)

Now, imagine you are writing a spliterator for a source that is only described by an Iterator.  What quality of decomposition can you get?  Basically, all you can do is divide the source into "first" and "rest".  That's about as bad as it gets.  The result is a computation tree that is very "right-heavy".

The spliterator that you get from a data structure has more to work with; it knows the layout of the data, and can use that to give better splits, and therefore better parallel performance.  The spliterator for ArrayList can always divide in half, and retains knowledge of exactly how much data is in each half.  That's really good.  The spliterator from a balanced tree can get good distribution (since each half of the tree has roughly half the elements), but isn't quite as good as the ArrayList spliterator because it doesn't know the exact sizes.  The spliterator for a LinkedList is about as bad as it gets; all it can do is (first, rest).  And the same for deriving a spliterator from an iterator.

Now, all is not necessarily lost; if the work per element is high, you can overcome bad splitting.  But if you're doing a small amount of work per element, you'll be limited by the quality of splits from your spliterator.

Answer (score 5):

There are several problems with your benchmark.

1. `Stream<Integer>` cannot be compared to `IntStream` because of boxing overhead.
2. You aren't doing anything with the result of the calculation, which makes it hard to know whether the code is actually being run
3. You are benchmarking with `System.nanoTime` instead of using a proper benchmarking tool.

Here's a JMH-based benchmark:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ContiguousSet;
import com.google.common.collect.DiscreteDomain;
import com.google.common.collect.Range;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;

public class Ranges {

    final static int SIZE = 10_000_000;

    @Benchmark
    public long intStream() {
        Stream<Integer> st = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, SIZE).boxed();

        return st.parallel().mapToInt(x -> x).sum();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public long contiguousSet() {
        ContiguousSet<Integer> cs = ContiguousSet.create(Range.closed(1, SIZE), DiscreteDomain.integers());
        Stream<Integer> st = cs.stream();

        return st.parallel().mapToInt(x -> x).sum();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        new Runner(
                new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(".*Ranges.*")
                .forks(1)
                .warmupIterations(5)
                .measurementIterations(5)
                .build()
        ).run();
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
Benchmark                  Mode   Samples        Score  Score error    Units
b.Ranges.contiguousSet    thrpt         5       13.540        0.924    ops/s
b.Ranges.intStream        thrpt         5       27.047        5.119    ops/s
```

So `IntStream.range` is about twice as fast as `ContiguousSet`, which is perfectly reasonable, given that ContiguousSet doesn't implement its own Spliterator and uses the default from `Set`

Comment: Thank you for the tip about JMH. I was not aware of its existence.